# I want to use transition effects in react app. What type/ library for animation in react app should I use according to the latest trend?

Tags: reactjs

I want to use some transition effects in my react js app. I am using function components in my app.
How do I include transition effects in app according to the business requirement these days?
I want to use animation such that on every render I can see the effect. It would be great if someone can help me out with an example.

Comment: Probably Framer Motion.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a library, I would suggest react-spring
https://react-spring.io/ it is based on spring physics, If you want to read about that more check this out https://www.joshwcomeau.com/animation/a-friendly-introduction-to-spring-physics/
And there is also another good option which is framer motion https://www.framer.com/motion/ which apparently offers more possibilities maybe out of the box (I personally have never tried it before)
For examples you can check their websites they have good examples.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what effect you are trying to generate.
css can be used by itself to generate animations or transitions.

You want to see the effect on each render?
i.e. You want to tie the effect to the react render cycle?

non-memoized values will change on every render
You could use a simple statement like `const trigger = {};`
Then react to trigger with a useEffect

useEffect(() => { do something }, [trigger]);

finally, visual effect.. apply a class based on state and use setTimeout to remove the state (and therefore the class)

This could be overly involved for exactly what you are trying to achieve but this works for all possible flows based on the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example with div element is moving to according vertical scroll position .
Look carefully.

First, Set the position using useState and define the window.onscroll function.

```
const [cardTop, setCardTop] = useState(0);

window.onscroll = function() {
    if (window.pageYOffset < 30) {
        setCardTop(window.pageYOffset + 'px');
    }
};
```

Second, Set the style's top as state variable.

```
<div className='card t-card' id='tCard' style={{top:`${cardTop}`}}> ...
```

Congratulations. It probably act exactly.

It's similar to use Jquery or another Javascript, Only use state variable.

Thanks.